# Issue with Sending Ephemeral Messages on app_home_opened Event

Tags: node.js, slack

I'm encoutering difficulties with sending ephemeral messages when handling the 'app_home_opened' event event in my slack app, The goal is to display a message to users when they navigate to a specific channel.

I'm using @slack/bolt library in nodejs

here is my code to show the message

```
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt');


const app = new App({
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
});
// console.log('SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET:', process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET);



app.event('app_home_opened', async ({ event, client }) => {
    try {
        console.log('Received app_home_opened event:', event);

        const channelID = 'CDV45R12B';
        const commandMessage = 'To submit a ticket, use the command `/ticket-request`.';
        
        await client.chat.postEphemeral({
            channel: event.user,
            text: commandMessage,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error handling app_home_opened event:', error);
    }
});


(async () => {
    await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);
    console.log('⚡️ Bolt app is running!');
})()
```

I have added the neccesary scopes "chat:write and app_mentions:read".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `chat.postEphemeral` method requires not only the `channel` but also the `user` parameters to be defined as stated on the method's documentation page here: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral.